# Virtual server problem in apache's httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, nameserver, httpd.conf, virtualhost

When I use the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName subone.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain/subone/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
ServerName subtwo.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain/subtwo/
</VirtualHost>
```

Every query goes to /var/www/subdomain/subone. Including:
domain.tld, subone.domain.tld, subtwo.domain.tld, ...

When I add a "NameVirtualHost *" to the beginning of the file, everything goes to /var/www

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the port numbers maybe?
e.g.
NameVirtualHost *:80

and 
VirtualHost *:80

Comment: I thought those were implied? I've added it just in case.
I also didn't have a "ServerName", adding that changed the behavious aswel.

Comment: It's not implied.  Also, ensure that <VirtualHost *:80> matches whatever you have defined as NameVirtualHost. Example: NameVirtualHost *:80

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion your are missing this entry in your httpd.conf

`NameVirtualHost ip_of_your_server:80`

--
Regards,
Robert